# one-to-many form with checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, one-to-many, nested-attributes, form-for

I have a one to many relationship between Admins and Users.

```
Admin has_many :users
Admin accepts_nested_attributes_for :users

User belongs_to :admin
```

I'd like the admin edit form to include a list of all users with checkboxes next to each user, so that the admin can choose which users are associated with that admin.

I know how to do this for a many to many association, but have no idea how to make it work for the 'simpler' version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is created form with form_tag  and for checkbox instead simple user you can use

```
<%= checkbox_tag "user_ids[]" %>
```

It will pass array of user_id and on controller side you can iterate the array of user_ids and assign to admin.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I ended up doing this and it worked great:
`
<%= hidden_field_tag "admin[user_ids][]" %>
<% @users_list.each do |user| %>
    <%= check_box_tag "admin[user_ids][]", user.id, user.admin_id.eql?(@admin.id)%>
    <%= user.name %>
<% end %>`